# How to set WriteMode when using a sesssion to upload large file

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I'm writing a script to upload files to Dropbox using python dropbox module (V2). The files will be uploaded in one go or via a session depending on the size. The relevant code is as follows:

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    try:
        file_size = os.path.getsize(file)
        chunk_size = 4*1024*1024
        if file_size < chunk_size:
            dbx.files_upload(f.read(), file_to, mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite)
        else:
            session_start_result = dbx.files_upload_session_start(f.read(chunk_size))
            cursor = dropbox.files.UploadSessionCursor(session_id=session_start_result.session_id, offset=f.tell())
            commit = dropbox.files.CommitInfo(path=file_to)
            while f.tell() < file_size:
                if (file_size - f.tell()) <= chunk_size:
                    dbx.files_upload_session_finish(f.read(chunk_size), cursor, commit)
                else:
                    dbx.files_upload_session_append_v2(f.read(chunk_size), cursor)
                    cursor.offset = f.tell()
```

However, this will raise an error if a the session option is used to upload a large file with the same name as one already in the Dropbox folder. For a small file upload, you can set the WriteMode, but I couldn't find any documentation on how to do this when using a session/cursor.

Any help or a nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using upload sessions, you can set the `WriteMode` on [the `dropbox.files.CommitInfo` object](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html#dropbox.files.CommitInfo), via the `mode` parameter. That should be a `dropbox.files.WriteMode`, just like in the small file scenario.

You then pass that `CommitInfo` to `files_upload_session_finish` like you're already doing.